# Code coverage dropped after updating libraries and jacoco exclude not working

Tags: gradle, mockito, code-coverage, junit4, jacoco

I have upgradedmy project lib versions (gradle 7.2/spring boot 2.7.13/junit 4.13) and after that cove coverage dropped from 84% to 49%(without any functional change and new classes addition) and when checked jacoco report, the code coverage is 0 for the classes that are using mockito runner (@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)). i tried @injectmock anotation to make these classes picked up but it didnt work, now im trying to exclude these classes and that is also not working.Please help.

test class:(its under accept package com/**/accept)

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AbstractProcTest {

    private LSD ls = new LSD();

    private AbstractProc processor = new SmallProc(ls);

    @Mock
    private RestClient restClient;


}
```

build.gradle

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        excludeTags "ignoreaccept"
    }
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport 
}
```

jacoco-settings:

```
jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    violationRules {
        rule {
            element = 'BUNDLE'
            excludes = ['**/com/vk/isr/kvr/accept/**/*']
            limit {
                minimum = 0.84
            }
        }
    }
}


jacocoTestReport {
    group 'documentation'
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination file("${buildDir}/result/report")
    }
}


jacocoTestCoverageVerification.mustRunAfter jacocoTestReport


check.dependsOn jacocoTestReport
check.dependsOn jacocoTestCoverageVerification
compileJava.dependsOn(processResources)
```

I also tried giving @Tag("ignoreaccept") on top of test class but still the code coverage is not being increased.